# DecimalUpDown Doesn't show correct value when editing directly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, numericupdown

I'm using the Extended WPF ToolKit's DecimalUpDown control (v1.7). The control behaves as I expect when using the spinner controls but not when text is edited directly. This is a basic MVVM WPF app with the control bound to a View Model decimal property named `CurrentWidth`.

In the ViewModel there are various validation rules being enforced for `CurrentWidth`, at the end of the property it  does a `RaisePropertyChange("CurrentWidth");` sometimes leaving CurrentWidth unchanged if the value doesn't validate.

All the error checking, value reverting etc works when change is made with the spinner controls. When the user enters text directly in the box, the validation still works but the box is left showing what the user entered.  When I send out some debug info, both the Value property and Text properties have the correct unmodified value but the box still shows the user entered value. I tried adding a LostFocus event handler and called `InvalidateVisual()` on the sender control and even tried an `UpdateLayout()` as well but after tabbing off the control, the user entered text still shows.  Anyone know how to get it to reflect the actual current value?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [WPFToolkit 1.8.0.](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/94866) This bug is solved there.